# select get results then delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I need to select single entry from DB, then delete selected row but I also need to get result of selection.

```
delete from Emails where Emails.Id in (select top (1) t.Id from Emails t)
```

this query returns number of deleted rows, but i need to get as result the selected row. How to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: `top 1` without order by can return any row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case your can do something like this

```
delete top(1) from Emails
output deleted.*
```

Here's more information about [`output`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1333/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

> I need to select single entry from DB, then delete selected row but I
>   also need to get result of selection.

you can declare a variable, store the selected single value in it, and then delete your record:

```
Declare @v int
set @v= (select top (1) t.Id from Emails t)

delete from Emails where Emails.Id=@v
```

Comment: This has a race condition if multiple threads are running it.